# Librosa CQT: why don't these simple sine waves fall neatly into their frequency bins?

Tags: spectrogram, librosa

I've been trying out Librosa and testing the cqt function for a (music-related) project. In order to verify that I'm using it correctly, I inputted the sum of two sine waves, corresponding to two notes: A3 and C5. The result was not exactly as I had expected. The two bins for A3 and C5 do have the strongest energy, but the bins around them [are not symmetric at all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFkz5.png).

Is this a normal result or am I doing something wrong? I checked and the cqt frequencies align perfectly with the notes. Also, when I tried out chroma_cqt, the result was [almost perfectly symmetric](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCKx9.png).

```
import librosa
import librosa.display
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sr = 44100
s = np.linspace(0,5,5*sr)
f1 = librosa.midi_to_hz(69) # A, 440 Hz
f2 = librosa.midi_to_hz(84) # C, 1047 Hz
y = np.sin(2*np.pi*f1*s)+np.sin(2*np.pi*f2*s)


fmin = librosa.midi_to_hz(36) # C2, 65.4 Hz
n_octaves = 6
n_bins = 12*n_octaves

n_fft = 8192
hop_length = n_fft//4


## CQT implementation
# chromogram
Cr = librosa.feature.chroma_cqt(y=y, sr=44100, hop_length=hop_length, norm=None, n_octaves=7)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
librosa.display.specshow(Cr, hop_length=hop_length,
                         x_axis='time',
                         y_axis='chroma', sr=sr,
                         cmap="Greys")
plt.colorbar(format='%+2.0f dB')
plt.title('spectrogram')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

# spectrogram
C =librosa.core.cqt(y, sr=44100,
                    hop_length=hop_length, 
                    filter_scale=2, fmin=fmin,
                    n_bins=n_bins)
C_dB = librosa.amplitude_to_db(np.abs(C))
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))

librosa.display.specshow(C_dB, x_axis='time',
                         hop_length=hop_length,
                         y_axis='cqt_note', sr=sr,
                         cmap="Greys")
plt.colorbar(format='%+2.0f dB')
plt.title('spectrogram')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

That could be due to the way frequencies appear in a log scale.

I just noticed that librosa now has a variable length QT (vqt) implementation, results looks much better from this perspective.

```
V = librosa.vqt(y, sr=sr, fmin=fmin, n_bins=72, hop_length=hop_length)
logC = librosa.amplitude_to_db(np.abs(V))
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))
librosa.display.specshow(logC, sr=sr, x_axis='time', y_axis='cqt_note', fmin=fmin, cmap='coolwarm')
```

[image: vqt results]